# Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy at the push of a button

Tags: uitabbar

I am getting this error when I try to modally present a new view controller.
When the button is pressed, the controller is presented, but an error pops up

Attempt to present <Meeting.SettingsPhotoViewController: 0x119e196b0> on <UITabBarController: 0x10a81ce00> (from <Meeting.ProfileViewController: 0x10570bf90>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.

I don’t know if this matters, but I have 3 controllers associated with the tap bar controllers and one controller that is not associated with it

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    startSettings()
    
}


@IBAction func settingsPhotoPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "settingsToPhotoSettings", sender: self)
}
```